# how can I make datetime format with variables ms access

Tags: datetime, ms-access

I like to pass datatime to a function but can't format it with variables.
I like to call a function with datatime like this.
`function(#Me.frmDate/Me.frmMonth/Me.frmYear#)`.
But as you know, this code can't be compiled.
I would like to know correct code.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can call your function, which has `Date/Time` data type parameter like this:

```
function(DateSerial(Me.frmYear, Me.frmMonth, Me.frmDate))
```

Here `Me.frm*` fields should contain valid numbers for desired date